# Python : no JSON object could be decoded

Tags: python, json

I am trying to run this app:

https://github.com/bmjr/guhTrends

I have `python 2.7.x` running the following script at command line. I reckon it was written using `python3.x`. What is deprecated in the code below?

```
import urllib
import json
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

dates = urllib.request.urlopen('http://charts.spotify.com/api/tracks/most_streamed/global/weekly/')
dataDates = json.loads(dates.read().decode())
```

the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "DataMining.py", line 6, in <module>
    dates = urllib.request.urlopen('http://charts.spotify.com/api/tracks/most_streamed/global/weekly/')
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'request'
```

Comment: Please reduce your code snippet to the absolute minimum required to reproduce your problem. Please copy-paste that *exact* program into your question. As it stands, your code snippet has syntax errors. See [mcve] for more info.

Comment: To amend the comment from Rob, in 90% of cases when making a verifiable examole, you will understand what went wrong with your code. And, if not, someone will be able to offer you insight into your issue. But without a verifiable example, neither are possible.

Comment: At the moment, http://charts.spotify.com/api/tracks/most_streamed/global/weekly/ doesn't return JSON. It returns a status code of 502, and HTML, not JSON.

Comment: As near as I can tell, your problem is on line 10 so all that other stuff is not needed for this discussion. Try printing the data before you do the json operation. You'll see an html page telling you about the error. When you can't decode something, the first step is always to print that something to see if its the stuff you think it is.

Comment: I have reduced the code, changed it back to the original, and linked verifiable examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That script won't work under python2 as `urllib` of python2 **has no request module**.

Use [**urllib2.urlopen**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html#urllib2.urlopen) instead of `urllib.request` if you want start running that script under `python2` .

To get python script work on bith (`python2` and `python3`) use [**six module**](https://pythonhosted.org/six/) which is **Python 2 and 3 Compatibility Library**.

```
from six.moves import urllib
import json
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

dates = urllib.request.urlopen('http://charts.spotify.com/api/tracks/most_streamed/global/weekly/')
dataDates = json.loads(dates.read().decode())
```

Answer (score 0):

You're requesting a resource that is not currently available (I'm seeing a 504). Since this could potentially happen any time you request a remote service, always check the status code on the response; it's not that your code is necessarily wrong, in this case it's that you're assuming the response is valid JSON without checking whether the request was successful.

Check the [`urllib` documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html) to see how to do this (or, preferably, follow the recommendation at the top of that page and use the [`requests` package](http://requests.readthedocs.org/) instead).

Comment: thank you, now I see a 504 too. I will check the docs. I voted for the answer above because it tackled the deprecation/compatibility issue, but your answer was crucial as well.